# Activate buttons using another button in pyqt5, should I use if statement?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

here is how it's going...

I want to press the SD bottom and that will activate the Four test point down
and assign the following IP address to them,
so when I press on TP1 it will take the TP1 address and so on.

I am trying to do it with if function but its not working!!
is there any better way to do it?

the code :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QGridLayout, QLCDNumber)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from QLed import QLed

class MainProg(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):


        super(MainProg, self).__init__()


        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.setFixedSize(1366, 768)

        self.AASD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.AASD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 31, 32))
        self.AASD.clicked.connect(self.ASD)

        self.AAHD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.AAHD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 70, 31, 32))
        #self.AASD.clicked.connect(self.AHD)


        self.AASD.setText("SD")
        self.AAHD.setText("HD")


        ##################################################3
        self.Testpunk1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 460, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 510, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk3 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 595, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk4 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 650, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk5 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 465, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk6 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 515, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk7 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 600, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk8 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 650, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk1.setText("TP1")
        self.Testpunk2.setText("TP2")
        self.Testpunk3.setText("TP3")
        self.Testpunk4.setText("TP4")

        self.Testpunk5.setText("TP5")
        self.Testpunk6.setText("TP6")
        self.Testpunk7.setText("TP7")
        self.Testpunk8.setText("TP8")



        ###################the LEDs####################

        self.Tp1 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 465, 25, 25))
        self.Tp1.value = False

        self.Tp2 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 600, 25, 25))
        self.Tp2.value = False

        self.Tp3 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(745, 470, 25, 25))
        self.Tp3.value = False

        self.Tp4 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(745, 605, 25, 25))
        self.Tp4.value = False

    def TPLed(self):

        self.Tp1.value = True  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp3.value = True  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp2.value = True  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp4.value = True


    def ASD(self):


        self.TPLed()
        TP1 = "239.168.1.6:1112"
        TP2 = "239.168.1.7:1116"
        TP3 = "239.168.1.6:1132"
        TP4 = "239.168.1.6:1136"
        TP5 = "239.168.2.6:2113"
        TP6 = "239.168.2.7:2122"
        TP7 = "239.168.2.8:2132"
        TP8 = "239.168.2.9:2142"


        if  self.Testpunk1.click():
            myurl = TP1
            print("TP1 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk2.click():
            myurl = TP2
            print("TP2 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk3.click():
            myurl = TP3
            print("TP3 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk4.click():
            myurl = TP4
            print("TP4 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk5.click():
            myurl = TP5
            print("TP5 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk6.click():
            myurl = TP6
            print("TP6 is playing")
            pass
        if self.Testpunk7.click():
            myurl = TP7
            print("TP7 is playing")
            pass

        if self.Testpunk8.click():
            myurl = TP8
            print("TP8 is playing")
            pass

    def AADH(self):
        #the same with different IP addresses
        pass




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = MainProg()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but here goes the answer.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QGridLayout, QLCDNumber)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from QLed import QLed

class MainProg(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainProg, self).__init__()

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.setFixedSize(1366, 768)

        self.AASD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.AASD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 31, 32))
        self.AASD.clicked.connect(self.ASD)

        self.AAHD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.AAHD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 70, 31, 32))
        #self.AASD.clicked.connect(self.AHD)

        self.AASD.setText("SD")
        self.AAHD.setText("HD")

        ##################################################3
        self.Testpunk1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 460, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 510, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk3 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 595, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk4 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 650, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk5 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 465, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk6 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 515, 31, 32))

        self.Testpunk7 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 600, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk8 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.Testpunk8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 650, 31, 32))
        self.Testpunk1.setText("TP1")
        self.Testpunk2.setText("TP2")
        self.Testpunk3.setText("TP3")
        self.Testpunk4.setText("TP4")

        self.Testpunk5.setText("TP5")
        self.Testpunk6.setText("TP6")
        self.Testpunk7.setText("TP7")
        self.Testpunk8.setText("TP8")

        # You do need to set objectName to access from self.sender
        self.Testpunk1.setObjectName("TP1")
        self.Testpunk2.setObjectName("TP2")
        self.Testpunk3.setObjectName("TP3")
        self.Testpunk4.setObjectName("TP4")

        self.Testpunk5.setObjectName("TP5")
        self.Testpunk6.setObjectName("TP6")
        self.Testpunk7.setObjectName("TP7")
        self.Testpunk8.setObjectName("TP8")

        self.Testpunk1.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk2.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk3.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk4.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk5.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk6.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk7.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)
        self.Testpunk8.clicked.connect(self.tpButtonClicked)

        # ##################the LEDs####################
        self.Tp1 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 465, 25, 25))
        self.Tp1.value = False

        self.Tp2 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 600, 25, 25))
        self.Tp2.value = False

        self.Tp3 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(745, 470, 25, 25))
        self.Tp3.value = False

        self.Tp4 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Circle)
        self.Tp4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(745, 605, 25, 25))
        self.Tp4.value = False

    def TPLed(self):
        self.Tp1.setValue(True)  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp3.setValue(True)  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp2.setValue(True)  # the LED ON code
        self.Tp4.setValue(True)

    def tpButtonClicked(self):
        TP1 = "239.168.1.6:1112"
        TP2 = "239.168.1.7:1116"
        TP3 = "239.168.1.6:1132"
        TP4 = "239.168.1.6:1136"
        TP5 = "239.168.2.6:2113"
        TP6 = "239.168.2.7:2122"
        TP7 = "239.168.2.8:2132"
        TP8 = "239.168.2.9:2142"

        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP1":
            myurl = TP1
            print("TP1 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP2":
            myurl = TP2
            print("TP2 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP3":
            myurl = TP3
            print("TP3 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP4":
            myurl = TP4
            print("TP4 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP5":
            myurl = TP5
            print("TP5 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP6":
            myurl = TP6
            print("TP6 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP7":
            myurl = TP7
            print("TP7 is playing")
            return
        if self.sender().objectName() == "TP8":
            myurl = TP8
            print("TP8 is playing")
            return

    def ASD(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, self.TPLed) # Using timer as QLed uses it in its tests

    def AADH(self):
        #the same with different IP addresses
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = MainProg()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What happened was that you were trying check a clicked event within a slot triggered from another button. Your conditional statements would never be True.

I simply connected those buttons to one slot and as you can access `self.sender`, I've set a `objectName` that way, you could check it later. I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Eliakin Costa
that's exactly what I want